# Android porting UI

Tags: android

I created an UI for my Android Project. However I was wondering whether it is possible to create a library out of it so that you can sort of "load" the UI in the onCreate method of my Activity.

I read about putting my created classes into a .jar file, however what about main.xml where my UI is built they way it looks.
If I could actually load the UI it should be possible to add tweaks to the UI for the same Activity if someone for example likes a different design of his app.
I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Are you talking about custom views? If so, have a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html it might be able to help.

Comment: Lets say i created my own UI. I dont want it to be implemented directly in my Activity but rather be loaded so that i can customize it individually if some people wish for a tweaked design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a library project.

Typically it's not easy to arrive at a simple JAR, although this is a much complained about limitation!

So just import your "library" project in any other project you would like to reference.

I've personally created a few extensions of the Activity class where setContentView is already called in onCreate.

In your application project just extend your custom activity from the library project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library project.

Take a look at this project and his implementation:

[Holo Everywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere)